# Proving set is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have been trying to prove the following statement:

Let $X \subset(0,+\infty)=\{x \in \mathbb{R} ; x>0\}$ be an uncountable set. Prove that there exists $\rho>0(\rho \in \mathbb{R})$ such that $X_{\rho}=\{x \in X ; x>\rho\}$ is infinite.

Until now, i guess the most promissing attempt of mine went like this:

"Suppose by contradiction that for every $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\rho > 0$, the set $X_{\rho}$ is finite. If that is the case, given $\rho>0$, one can obtain $\alpha \in X_{\rho}$ such that $\alpha \geq t, \forall t \in X_{\rho}$. Now, because $t \in X_{\rho}$, we see that $t \in X$ and $t > \rho $"

I was not able to do any better then starting the proof by contradiction and writing a few definitions to the paper. I am trying to achieve a contradiction (i am guessing that has something to do with proving that $X$ is countable, but i can't seem to get there).

I also tried to put $X_{\rho}$ in bijection with an infinite set, but i could not make it.

I have also tried to argue that $X_{\rho}$ contains an infinite subset and should therefore be infinite, but that did not work out either.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that $X =\bigcup_n X_{1/n}$. If $X_{\rho}$ is finite for each $\rho$ then this would be a countable union of finite sets and hence $X$ would be countable.

Comment: Super nice! I wrote a preliminary draft here and one of the inclusions followed from the archimedian property, while the other followed from the definition of the set $X_{1 / n}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the union $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_{1/n}.$$
How is this union related to $X$?